# How do I change this code to close the file once done?

Tags: c#

I found this piece of code somewhere that I don't remember and it works just fine unzipping a file (`infile`) from a zip file (`inzip`). Note, that in reality, `inzip` only ever contains one file.

Except it doesn't close the file when it's done.

Can someone (1) decipher what it is doing and (2) more importantly, give me some idea how to close the zip file (`inzip`) when it's done or provide a more readable way to accomplish this.

```
dataout = new string(
        (new System.IO.StreamReader(
         System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead(inzip)
         .Entries.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(infile, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
         .FirstOrDefault()
         .Open())
         .ReadToEnd())
         .ToArray());
```

Comment: The code is so bad that I'm a bit reluctant to try to clean it up for an answer since I need to go through several steps from the code you wrote to code that is actually usable. Here's the result: `using (var zipfile = ZipFile.OpenRead(inzip))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(zipfile.Entries.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(infile, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)).FirstOrDefault().Open()))
    {
        dataout = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }`

Comment: This is one of the worst "one-line Monsters" I've ever seen. Aside from being excruciatingly painful to read, it actually doesn't allow file closure. You have to extrapolate single pieces.

Comment: That code looks like somebody tried to impress someone with their mad Fluent skillz. Looks like self-defeat to me...

Comment: It's a good thing that you can't remember where you got the code from. If you ever remember it, remember to never go there again!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to tackle this one step at a time. As I wrote in my comment, this code is so bad that it is hard to just go from the code in the question to the final answer as this will skip several steps.

So here's the original code, with all its original problems:

```
dataout = new string(
        (new System.IO.StreamReader(
         System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead(inzip)
         .Entries.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(infile, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
         .FirstOrDefault()
         .Open())
         .ReadToEnd())
         .ToArray());
```

We'll have to start with the innermost object, which is the zip file, so let's first close that, which we can do using `Dispose`, or rewriting the code to use `using`:

```
using (var zipfile = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead(inzip))
{
    dataout = new string(
            (new System.IO.StreamReader(
             zipfile
             .Entries.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(infile, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
             .FirstOrDefault()
             .Open())
             .ReadToEnd())
             .ToArray());
}
```

This, however, will unlikely fix all the problems. The `StreamReader` object should actually be closed before we close the zip file, so let's deal with that:

```
using (var zipfile = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead(inzip))
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(zipfile.Entries.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(infile, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)).FirstOrDefault().Open()))
{
    dataout = new string(reader.ReadToEnd().ToArray());
}
```

But then, what about `reader.ReadToEnd().ToArray()`? This reads a string, converts it to an array, which is then used as a parameter to construct a string.

How about just:

```
using (var zipfile = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead(inzip))
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(zipfile.Entries.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(infile, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)).FirstOrDefault().Open()))
{
    dataout = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

OK, so that should do it.

**If** you forego *all* error-checking, like

- What if the file is not found in the archive?
- What if the file is not a text file?
- What is the encoding of the file? UTF8? Windows-1252? UTF16?

Comment: Encoding is UTF8.

Comment: I agree whole completely not to go back to where I got the code.  I was in a hurry and it worked.  I didn't find the close problem until much later.